# Calculate the probability of any one independent scenario occurring

Tags: probability, density-function, independence

I have $3$ independent scenarios and I need to calculate the probability of any one of them occurring.

I’ve calculated the probability of the $i$-th event as:

1. : $1-\big(\frac{70000-1}{70000}\big)^1  = 0.00001428...$
2. : $1-\big(\frac{50000-1}{50000}\big)^1  = 0.00002$
3. : $1-\big(\frac{75000-1}{75000}\big)^1  = 0.00001333...$

In each scenario, the only thing that changes is the population size.

What would the function look like to tell me the probability of any one of these scenarios occurring?

Thank you!

Comment: Try finding the probability none of them occur...

Answer (score 1):

The complementary event is none of them occur.

That is probability of at least $1$ event occur is equal to $1$ minus the probability that none of them occur.

Let $p_i$ be the probability that event $i$ happens, then you are looking for

$$1-\prod_{i=1}^3(1-p_i)$$

You can adapt to your formula by writing $p_i$ as a function of $N_i$, the population size.